# Multiple Intersecting Universes

Tags: universe, multiverse

I am not a relativist or cosmologist, so this is very qualitative:

I imagine a pair of universes, where each has two spatial dimensions (plus time), embedded in a 3-D (plus time) space, and these two universes spatially intersect along a line. That line might even act as a "portal', from one universe to the other, for the flatlander residents...

Generalize that to a pair of universes where each has three spatial dimensions (plus time), embedded in a 4-D (or more, plus time) space, and these two universes spatially intersect, probably along a plane. Are they any theories, considered to be somewhat plausible, where 1) there are 4 or more spatial dimensions (plus time), 2) Our three spatial dimensions (plus time) universe is embedded within that, 3) there is at least one other universe (which also manifests internally to be three spatial dimensions, plus time) embedded in that higher dimensional space, and 4) that universe intersects ours? I am thinking probably not because, if there was one such other intersecting universe there would be an infinite number intersecting ours and so, things would appear quite different for us than they currently do.

Comment: Sure.  Take two copies of Minkowski space, choose a global timelike coordinate $t$ and a global spacelike coordinate $x$ on each of them, and paste them together along the line $t=x$.

Comment: The universe is defined as the entirety of everything there is. "Parallel"  universes are therefor a misnomer. The one universe may have multiple parts that are communicating weakly, but then, there are absolutely no measurements that would even hint at that. To be historically more precise... the parallel universe idea was invented by physicists who still can't explain the one that they can see...

Comment: The (physical) universe is most certainly not "the entirety of everything there is" unless you believe either that the number 3 does not exist (in which case it's hard to interpret apparently sensible statements like "3 is a prime number") or that it is part of the universe (in which case it occupies some spatiotemporal location), either of which seems like a pretty dicy proposition.

Comment: @WillO: I am not talking about philosophy here but about rational scientific definitions of what the universe is. It's "the stuff" that can hit you in the head or drown you in a pond of water. There is absolutely no need to postulate several of those. There is one and that one may, as in case of event horizons of different kind, remove parts of itself from our observations (yes, one can be at the wrong place at the wrong time and miss the party...). The essential kicker is simply that only one of these has ever been observed... making any speculation about others non-science by default.

Comment: Wasn't the Higgs Boson energy, measured at the LHC, supposed to indicate something about multiple universes, according to the documentary "Particle Fever"? Something like 115 (forgot the units) means only one universe but 140 meant multiple? Prof. Kaplan was talking about that in the film. I think they measured 125, so it was inconclusive.

Comment: @David  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144337/how-can-the-mass-of-higgs-give-preference-to-susy-vs-multiverse

Comment: @CuriousOne:  If you are postulating that the number 3 does not exist, or  that it exists and is part of the universe, then you are most certainly talking about philosophy (and, in my opinion, not talking very sensibly about it).  If you deny both  of those things, but still assert that the universe consists of everything there is, then you are simply contradicting yourself.  Another word for that is blathering.

Comment: do these planes have the same physics ? how an object may choose between the direction of its spacetime and that of the other ?

Comment: @WillO: I am not postulating anything about "the number 3", at least not beyond the meaning of Sesame Street's Count von Count who likes to count occurrences of sufficiently similar looking baryonic matter. They are not part of a scientific description of nature. If you feel that Newton made a mistake when he didn't tell us how much "3" gravitates, that's something you have to take up with him. To me it's an irrelevant question. Are mathematics books part of the universe? Of course. Are their abstract contents relevant for physics? Nope.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  That's all fine, but you did in fact make a very strong statement to the effect that nothing exists beyond what is in the universe.  That's a philosophical position that I think would be very hard to defend.  From your most recent comment, I can't figure out whether you're retracting that statement or claiming that you're no longer interested in the question that you yourself raised (or possibly both or possibly neither) --- but I'm not sure whether that's because your comment is unclear or because I'm not fully digesting it.  [CONTINUED]

Comment: [CONTINUED]  If this is something you'd like to discuss further in chat, I'm happy to do that, but probably not till tomorrow.  If not, that's fine too.

Comment: @WillO: I'll be happy to discuss. Let me know, I will probably be around.

Comment: @WillO Your pasted-together construction is not a manifold and is thus hardly mainstream physics. And really the universe is everything there is, by definition.

Comment: @ChrisWhite:  I understood the question to be asking not for a single universe, but for two Universes, each imbedded in some larger manifold, and intersecting each other.  I agree that this is not mainstream physics (and I agree that it's not very interesting), but at least both universes are manifolds.   (Incidentally, in case this was overlooked, the point I was trying to make is that it's easy to give uninteresting examples of what the OP is looking for, which suggests that the question is not very interesting.)

Comment: @CuriousOne:  Not ignoring you, just very busy.   I hope we'll find a chance for that chat sometime soon.

Comment: @WillO: No worries, was busy myself, today.