# What does the discovery of the Higgs boson mean for SUSY?

Tags: supersymmetry, higgs, supersymmetric-particles

I've seen many differing opinions on how the discovery of the Higgs boson (specifically due to its mass) has effected theories of Super Symmetry, but all seem fairly biased.
I'm wondering if someone could explain which SUSY models are invalidated (if any), why the mass of sparticles being hugely different to their counterparts is important/unimportant?

i.e. "SUSY is invalid due to the Higgs being much more massive than predicted in their models (so sparticles must have >> mass than their counterparts)"

whilst also seeing,

"SUSY models are favoured, and only need to be adjusted slightly to compensate for the Higgs mass"

Comment: A balanced answer by Lubos Motle  to a similar question can be found here :  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129004/

Answer (score -1):

The discovery of the Higgs boson is one of the main aspects for introducing SUSY. As for the second order Feynman diagram for Higgs mechanism the divergence couldn't be cancelled without assuming supersymmetry. I don't remember the exact calculation. There is a similar argument where there are no supersymmetric partner had been discovered for the photon or any other particle. It is supposed that it exists in tera electron volt scale. However, supersymmetry breaking is a very active field of research until now.